# How to find URL of google spreadsheet using spreadsheet ID using google java client?

Tags: google-api, google-api-java-client

How to find URL of google spreadsheet using spreadsheet ID using  google java client? I don't want to build a string. I want to make call to google REST API and find out.

Comment: Go though the google drive API.  File id is also a sheet id.  that is assuming the file type is a google sheet.

Comment: My question is precise. i) I want to use java client ii) I already have ID, it is the URL that I want.

Answer (score 0):

[Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) with [search parm](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters) using the [mime type for a sheet](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/mime-types)

> mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'

Code from the documentation.

```
/**
   * Retrieve a list of File resources.
   *
   * @param service Drive API service instance.
   * @return List of File resources.
   */
  private static List<File> retrieveAllFiles(Drive service) throws IOException {
    List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
    Files.List request = service.files().list();

    do {
      try {
        FileList files = request.execute();

        result.addAll(files.getItems());
        request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
      } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred: " + e);
        request.setPageToken(null);
      }
    } while (request.getPageToken() != null &&
             request.getPageToken().length() > 0);

    return result;
  }
```

response contains:

Remember unless the user has access to the files the link wont work for them

```
"selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/1-0ReBjBqKh_Q9r1BDsC_BB9JgkeLoFPkDIXFcXiqQZ", 
"alternateLink": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-0ReBjBqKh_Q9r1BDsC_BB9JgkeLoFPkDIXFcXiqQZ/edit?usp=drivesdk", 
"embedLink": "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-0ReBjBqKh_Q9r1BDsC_BB9JgkeLoFPkDIXFcXiqQZ/htmlembed",
```

Comment: And how would I find URL from File class instance. There is no method for that.

Comment: file list returns a list of file resoreses.  URL should be in there https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files#resource alternateLink should be a full link to the file. there are a few more cant remember which one it is

Comment: JAVA client class File does not have method to access the URL.

Comment: it does its part of the response.

Comment: if you have the id you can also use file.get  https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get